# Export an array with custom objects

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

Basically, what I'm trying to do, is to retrieve all users from Active Directory and to save them in a .csv file, using a PowerShell script. In addition, I only want the attributes "name" and "samaccountname" to be listed. So here's the code:

```
$strFilter = "somefilter"
$objCollection = @()

$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"

$colProplist = "name", "samaccountname"
foreach ($i in $colPropList){$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)}

$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

foreach ($objResult in $colResults) {
  $objItem = $objResult.Properties

  $object = New-Object PSObject
  $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $objItem.name
  $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SAMAccountname -Value $objItem.samaccountname

  $objCollection+=$object
}

$objCollection # this gives me the output as wished
$objCollection | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\temp\exportfile.csv # this doesn't work
```

The Console Output looks like this:

```
Name                                SAMAccountname
----                                --------------
{IUSR_PFTT-DC1}                     {IUSR_PFTT-DC1}
{IUSR_PFVM-DC1}                     {IUSR_PFVM-DC1}
{IUSR_PFXX-DC1}                     {IUSR_PFXX-DC1}
```

But the exported .csv looks like this:

```
"Name","SAMAccountname"
"System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection","System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection"
"System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection","System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection"
"System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection","System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection"
"System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection","System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection"
```

Any ideas/solutions to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the user on your domain by using the Active Directory module:

```
import-module activedirectory
get-ADuser -filter * | select name,SamAccountName | ConvertTo-CSV | ac "C:\yourCSVFile.csv"
```

This will give you an output like this of all your users.

```
"name","SamAccountName"
"MATTHE_G","matthe_g"
"PUTINE_I","putine_i"
"COBB_C","cobb_c"
"BULL_T","bull_t"
"BAYOL_B","bayol_b"
"CAPPON_P","CAPPON_P"
....
```

**Note**: You will need to turn on the active directory windows feature to be able to use the `activedirectory` module. This can be found under 'Remote Sever Administration tools' tab in windows features.

Link: [For Cmdlet's in the AD module](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx)

Comment: I can't believe that I didn't stumble across this, while searching the internet for a solution... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to stick with the `DirectorySearcher` approach, change this:

```
foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
    {$objItem = $objResult.Properties

        $object = New-Object PSObject
        $object | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $objItem.name
        $object | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty -Name SAMAccountname -Value $objItem.samaccountname

        $objCollection+=$object
    }
```

into this:

```
$objCollection = $colResults | select -Expand Properties |
    select @{n='Name';e={$_.name}}, @{n='SAMAccountName';e={$_.samaccountname}}
```

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, is there a way to convert the property's `Value` from a `ResultPropertyValueCollection` to a string, rather than having to list each property individually (as you've done)?